# Почему middleware блокирует страницы?

Tags: auth, laravel-8

Использую вполне стандартный функционал. Использую два middleware по умолчанию: auth и guest. В файле app\Http\Kernel.php прописаны следующие строки:

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
         ...
    ];
```

Создал два контроллера для авторизации и регистрации: LoginController и RegisterController.
В LoginController в конструкторе пишу такой код:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    //Форма входа
    public function login() {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
    ...
```

В контроллере RegisterController пишу:

```
// Контроллер регистрации пользователя
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    // Форма регистрации
    public function register() {
       return view('auth.register');
    }
   ...
```

В route/web.php пишу такой код:

```
Route::group([
    'as' => 'auth.', // имя маршрута, например auth.index
    'prefix' => 'auth', // префикс маршрута, например auth/index
], function () {
// Форма регистрации
    Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register'])->name('register');

// Создание пользователя
    Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
//Форма входа
    Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login');

// аутентификация
    Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'autenticate'])->name('auth');

// выход
    Route::get('logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
});
```

Когда перехожу по адресу "сайт\public\auth\register" или "сайт\public\auth\login" ругается на несуществующую страницу. Почему так происходит? Кстати до этого все работало, а потом перестало. Когда закомментировал код в конструкторах RegisterController и LoginController на вышеупомянутые страницы стало переходить успешно, но при успешной авторизации юзер все равно видит контент страницы авторизации и регистрации. Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: @InDevX, роут мидлваре. Что это должно значит? Это я показал часть кода из файла Kernel.php где подключены вышеупомянутые мидлваре.

Comment: @InDevX, в файлике web.php содержатся все возможные роуты сайта. Я выложил код касательно этого файла. Без намеков говорите, так непонятно. Я показал полную картину где использовались middleware в контроллерах и в web.php.

Comment: @InDevX, все я понял, сами мидлваре перепределить возвращающиеся страницы.

Comment: @InDevX, я исправил ошибку. В самих мидлварах прописал редиректы правильные. И все заработало. Не обязательно надо использовть middleware в роутах, можно в контроллере условие задать в конструкторе. Это тоже будет работать.

Comment: Ну вы даже ошибку не правильно описали) Не на страницу не существующую ругается ведь... И про роуты я не к тому вёл, раньше нужно было отдельно это указывать

Comment: @InDevX, ну до решения проблемы middleware блокировал страницы, выводил 404 страницу в итоге. А сейчас корректно подгружает вьюшки из login и register

Answer (score 0):

Если кому интересно. Все заработало. В \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate прописываем следующее:

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{    
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('auth.login');
        }
    }
}
```

А в файле App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated также переопределяем роут.

```
   public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('user.index');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```